# Chartjs Array.join

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, javascript-objects, chart.js

Hi I'm creating some Charts for my server monitoring. I'm getting the Data with Php and pass it over as an Array to the javasccript:

```
<script>


    var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};

    var obj = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($names) ?>');
    var datenbarchart = obj.join(",");
    var obj1 = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($nameserver) ?>');

    var barChartData = {
        labels : [ obj1[0], obj1[1], obj1[2], obj1[3], obj1[4], obj1[5], obj1[6]],
        datasets : [
            {
                fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                data : [datenbarchart]
            }
        ]

    }
    window.onload = function(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
            responsive : true
        });
    }

    </script>
```

The problem part is, where I try to separate the first array with the join Method to get a String separated by `","`:

```
var datenbarchart = obj.join(",");
```

When I pass this over to the Chartjs Data where normally the Data looks like that: `data: [60,50,40,50]` It doesn't show any Data in the Chart. Isn't it possible to do that with a string, because it takes the whole string for every bar?

Comment: Because it didn't work with just `data: [obj]` , the bars are empty when I try that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.chartjs.org/docs/
data field is an Array so your syntax should be:

```
var datenbarchart = obj;
```

...

```
var barChartData = {
    labels : [ obj1[0], obj1[1], obj1[2], obj1[3], obj1[4], obj1[5], obj1[6]],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data : datenbarchart
        }
    ]

}
```

Comment: Oh wow yes you are right, my fault was that I wrote `data:[obj]` instead of just `data: obj`  Thank you very much!